# A script that juju ssh's into a node and then exits automatically - troubleshooting

Tags: bash, juju, maas, openstack

I have the following script that refuses to continue executing until I intervene and type CTRL+C:

```
juju ssh VMNode2MAAS.maas << EOF
if CONDITION_A > /dev/null 2>&1; then
   echo "Proceeding"
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt-get install -y ABC
   sudo mkdir -p /var/OLA
   cd /var/OLA
   sudo sh -c "DO SOMETHING HERE"
fi
logout

EOF
```

---

The above script pauses at the node's command prompt and refuses to exit. I tried "logout", "exit" but no cigar.

Any clue why juju ssh doesn't want to play ball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substituting exit 0 instead of logout solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the LOGOUT is required and instead of `sudo sh -c "DO SOMETHING HERE"` just enter the commands below `cd /var/OLA`

```
juju ssh VMNode2MAAS.maas << EOF
if CONDITION_A > /dev/null 2>&1; then
   echo "Proceeding"
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt-get install -y ABC
   sudo mkdir -p /var/OLA
   cd /var/OLA
fi
EOF
```

Comment: Bilal, I do need that sudo sh -c statement, since it's a complex piped statement that requires sudo access. I tried it without the exit, too - but didn't work.

Comment: Oh totally missed that. Great job.